# Liferay and relationships in it

Tags: liferay, relationship, crud, liferay-service-builder

I have a portlet, which can add/update/delete books and add authors. Moreover, you can choose existing authors when you try to add book.

[image]

And now I need to show how many books were written by each author in "author" table. How can I do it? Im a newbie in liferay and I even have no idea.

It's my service.xml

```
<entity name="Book" local-service="true" remote-service="true"  cache-enabled="false">

    <column name="bookId" type="long" primary="true" />
    <column name="bookName" type="String" />
    <column name="bookDescription" type="String" />
    <column name="authors" type="Collection" entity="Author" mapping-table="Books_Authors" />
    <finder return-type="Collection" name="bookName">
        <finder-column name="bookName"></finder-column>
    </finder>

</entity>

<entity name="Author" local-service="true" remote-service="true" cache-enabled="false">
    <column name="authorId" type="long" primary="true" />
    <column name="authorName" type="String" />
    <column name="books" type="Collection" entity="Book" mapping-table="Books_Authors" />

</entity>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Service Builder is your friend.

You just need to add a finder in your book entity in `service.xml`. If your entity has a field named `author`:

```
<finder name="Author" return-type="Collection">
    <finder-column name="author" />
</finder>
```

The execution of build-service will generate the methods `BookUtil.findByAuthor()` and `BookUtil.countByAuthor()`.

You can implement now the corresponding methods in `BookLocalServiceImpl`, calling the previous, and after another run of build-serivce, they're available in your `Util` class. Something like

```
public List<Book> getByAuthor(String author) {
    return getPersistence().findByAuthor(author);
}

public int countByAuthor(String author) {
    return getPersistence().countByAuthor(author);
}
```

After the last call to build-service you can call them from your `BookLocalServiceUtil`.

If you just want the count, don't retrieve all the collection. If there are many records, it's a bad idea. Invoke the count instead.

Comment: finder methods always start with `findBy`, therefore the finder method will be `findByAuthor` not `getByAuthor`.

Comment: You're right Parkash. Service Builder writes finders in Persistence classes, not Util. You have to include them in ServiceImpl to have them in LocalServiceUtil. Edited answer to clarify.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Juan! I'll try it soon.

Comment: There is still one mistake, that this finder method will be available through `BookUtil` only not `BookLocalService`. You can call them in a custom method of `BookLocalServiceImpl` and on building service, that custom method will be available through `BookLocalServiceUtil`.

Comment: That's exactly what I said :) Implement your new methods in `BookLocalServiceImpl` and they will be available in `BookLocalServiceUtil` after a build-service. Maybe I didn't explain it right

Comment: I've updated my post, could you please tell me what finder should I create?

Comment: @ParkashKumar please help me one more time!

Comment: @German, What problem are you having now? You have already accepted this answer.

Comment: Ok, I'll undo acceptancce. I don't understand what finder should I create. I can't create finder with `finder-column name = "authors"` cause it's have mapping-table, so what should I do?

Comment: Maybe you should keep questions simple, and not reediting them to change its conditions as you find new problems. You asked for a finder for a field "author", and so that was answered. Post a new question for a complex finder and it'll be easier to be helpful. It's really hard for people reading all those comments threads describing reeditions on the original question.

Comment: @JuanManuelRogado, sorry. I've created new question.