# Finder in Liferay's ServiceBuilder

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, relationships, liferay-service-builder

I know I had already asked this question, but I have misunderstandings yet. 
My previous question:
[Liferay and relationships in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39332811/liferay-and-relationships-in-it/39333415?noredirect=1#comment66137293_39333415)

In two words:
I have a portlet, which can add/update/delete books and add authors. Moreover, you can choose existing authors when you try to add book.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzUjn.png

And now I need to show how many books were written by each author in "author" table.

My service.xml:

```
<entity name="Book" local-service="true" remote-service="true"  cache-enabled="false">

    <column name="bookId" type="long" primary="true" />
    <column name="bookName" type="String" />
    <column name="bookDescription" type="String" />
    <column name="authors" type="Collection" entity="Author" mapping-table="Books_Authors" />
    <finder return-type="Collection" name="bookName">
        <finder-column name="bookName"></finder-column>
    </finder>

</entity>

<entity name="Author" local-service="true" remote-service="true" cache-enabled="false">
    <column name="authorId" type="long" primary="true" />
    <column name="authorName" type="String" />
    <column name="books" type="Collection" entity="Book" mapping-table="Books_Authors" />

</entity>
```

What finder should I create to achieve my goal? If I create bookName finder Im able to count how many different books I have. If I create authorName finder Im able to count how many authors I have. Im a little lost.

Thank you for your help, but I still have some questions:

1. How and where can I get `authorName` with `authorId`?
2. How can I use my `count` variable in my table in `view.jsp`?

   ```
   long count = BookLocalServiceUtil.countByAuthor(authorId);
   ```

---

```
    public void addBook(ActionRequest actionRequest, ActionResponse actionResponse) 
        throws IOException, PortletException {

        String bookName = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest,"bookName");
        String bookDescription = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "bookDescription");
        Long authorId = ParamUtil.getLong(actionRequest, "author");
        try {
        Book book = BookLocalServiceUtil.createBook(CounterLocalServiceUtil.increment());
        book.setBookName(bookName);
        book.setBookDescription(bookDescription);
        book.setAuthorId(authorId);
        book=BookLocalServiceUtil.addBook(book);
        String author = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "authorId");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.info(ADD_BOOK_ERROR, e);
        SessionErrors.add(actionRequest, "PortalExceptionError");   
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: One thing to clear first, can there be multiple authors for the single book?

Comment: @ParkashKumar, no.

Comment: Then, why are bothering to put `type=Collection` for `authors` column on `Book` entity? Shouldn't it be simple as `Integer/long` as you just need to put `authorId` from `Authors` book.

Comment: @ParkashKumar I've edited my post with answer

Comment: What are you putting in `authors` column of `Book` entity? there will be no requirement of mapping table, if you just put `authorId` there.

Comment: Mapping table is required, when you have `many-to-many` relationship between tables. e.g. `One book can have many authors` and `One author can have many books`.

Comment: In your case, you are saying that one book can have only one author. While, the second case automatically becomes true, that one author can many books.

Comment: @ParkashKumar, Sorry, my bad. In my case one author can write many books. What should I do in this case?

Comment: First clear, just one question as I earliest asked. Can one book have many authors???

Comment: @ParkashKumar, 100% No.

Comment: Ok, let me write answer for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In-case, if your `Book` can have only one `Author` (many-to-one), then following entity structure will work for you:

**service.xml**

```
<entity name="Book" local-service="true" remote-service="true" cache-enabled="false">
    <column name="bookId" type="long" primary="true"></column>
    <column name="bookName" type="String"></column>
    <column name="bookDescription" type="String"></column>
    <column name="authorId" type="long"></column>

    <finder return-type="Collection" name="Author">
        <finder-column name="authorId"></finder-column>
    </finder>
</entity>
<entity name="Author" local-service="true" remote-service="true" cache-enabled="false">
    <column name="authorId" type="long" primary="true"></column>
    <column name="authorName" type="String"></column>
</entity>
```

On successful build, above finder will generate two methods `findByAuthor(long authorId)` and `countByAuthor(long authorId)` in `BookUtil`. Then, you can implement these methods in `BookLocalServiceImpl` as following:

**BookLocalServiceImpl:**

```
public List<Book> findByAuthor(long authorId) {
    try {
        return BookUtil.findByAuthor(authorId);
    } catch (Exception ex) {}

    return null;
}

public int countByAuthor(long authorId) {
    try {
        return BookUtil.countByAuthor(authorId);
    } catch (Exception ex) {}

    return 0;
}
```

And on building service once again, you can use these methods in your action class and on view from `BookLocalServiceUtil`.

Also, you are using JSTL on your views, you need to add dependencies of the jars in `liferay-plugin-package.properties` as following:

**liferay-plugin-package.properties:**

```
portal-dependency-jars=\
    jstl-api.jar,\
    jstl-impl.jar
```

**Your Questions:**

> 1. How and where can I get `authorName` with `authorId`?

```
<liferay-ui:search-container>
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results results="${bookListArray}" />
    <liferay-ui:search-container-row className="builder.model.Book"
        keyProperty="bookId" modelVar="aBook">
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="bookName"
            name="book-Name" />
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="bookDescription"
            name="description" />
        <%
            Author bookAuthor = AuthorLocalServiceUtil.getAuthor(aBook.getAuthorId());
        %>
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="Author"
            value="<%=bookAuthor.getAuthorName()  %>" />
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp path="/html/actionBook.jsp" />
    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>
    <liferay-ui:search-iterator />
</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

> 2. How can I use my count variable in my table in `view.jsp`?

```
<liferay-ui:search-container>
    <liferay-ui:search-container-results results="${authorListArray}" />
    <liferay-ui:search-container-row className="builder.model.Author"
        keyProperty="authorId" modelVar="aAuthor">
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text property="authorName"
            name="author-Name" />
        <%
            int count = BookLocalServiceUtil.countByAuthor(aAuthor.getAuthorId());
        %>
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-text name="count"
            value="<%=String.valueOf(count)  %>" />
        <liferay-ui:search-container-column-jsp path="/html/actionAuthor.jsp" />
    </liferay-ui:search-container-row>
    <liferay-ui:search-iterator />
</liferay-ui:search-container>
```

Comment: In above given structure, you will require to set `authorId` when saving new `Book`.

Comment: But in your case how can I add author to book? In my situation I use addBookAuthors() method.

Comment: On `Book` creation screen, fill all authors in a drop-down, and set selected author's `authorId` in `Book` object.

Comment: From that `authorId`, we can get `Author` object (name) for UI use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I have two questions, look at my editted post. I decided not to create another question.

Comment: I attached my view.jsp. I don't understand, how can I paste count variable in second liferay conteiner. Help me please!

Comment: @German, See my updated answer. I have added code snippets on how to use that `count` and `author` variable on `view.jsp`

Comment: Despite the fact it seems super logic, but it doesn't work. I ask you from my heart to look into my project and find the error. I really need to do it.

It's my project: https://github.com/AlBoldyrev/Library/blob/master/bundles/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/LibraryBook-portlet/html/view.jsp

Comment: Allow me pull request. `parkash_swe@yahoo.com`

Comment: I sent you invitation, check this pls.

Comment: Sorry, that repository invitation does not exist.

Comment: I don't know what's the problem, but now I removed tick from "restrict editing" so you should be able to edit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123165/discussion-between-german-and-parkash-kumar).

Comment: @German, :p See my updated answer and [***snapshot***](http://i.imgur.com/YjbueMl.png)

Comment: Thanks a lot. You really helped me. It works now and it's very very cool. May be it will be easy for you to help me with another bounted question? :D

Comment: one more question, do you know how to get rid of scriplets here, using only el and jstl?