# Scoping in Liferay

Tags: java, scope, liferay, liferay-service-builder

---

Disclaimer:

I've asked this
[Finder in Liferay's ServiceBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39408982/finder-in-liferays-servicebuilder)

but discussion was filled with another questions so I decided to create new 
theme.

---

In my liferay application I can add book and author in my database. I can create book and select author to it. Now I need to show how many books were written by each author.

So I:

create special finder, implement new method:

```
public long countByAuthor(long authorId) throws SystemException {
      return getBookPersistence().countByAuthor(authorId);
}
```

and create new variable `long count = BookLocalServiceUtil.countByAuthor(authorId);`

But my question is, where should I use this variable? I think I should not use it in `addBook()` or `addAuthor()` methods, so what should I do?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5Cdh.png  -- it's my view.jsp. How can I use `count` in liferay conteiner?

Comment: Why don't you create a new file.jsp to show the author detail? It will be a detailed author and his books and there you could use that counter. You could use it inside a searchContainer that shows all the books of an author.

Comment: There is no different where to show table with author and it's book. Problem is, I don't know how to create table with some variable and data from database.

Comment: In order to create that table, just use search_container tag. Provide it with a list of books (use another finder to show the books of an author) and then use this finder to tell the search container the number of results

Comment: Could you please look at this and tell me why it doesn't work then? :)

https://github.com/AlBoldyrev/Library/blob/master/bundles/tomcat-7.0.62/webapps/LibraryBook-portlet/html/view.jsp

Comment: Are there any error trace on your logs? Could you call the LocalService out of the search container in order to test if it's working? For example in line 43, as <c:out value='<%=BookLocalServiceUtil.countByAuthor(validAuthorId)%>' />

Comment: I have 
07:17:54,995 ERROR [http-bio-8080-exec-3][render_portlet_jsp:132] null
builder.NoSuchAuthorException: No Author exists with the primary key 0

@Jorge


Out of the search conteiner it's not working.

Comment: Use a existing validAuthorId in the c:out in order to test if your finder it's working. If you got an author with id=1 just put <c:out value='<%=BookLocalServiceUtil.countByAuthor(1)%‌​>' />